# Remove / hide “Action” button from Slate Homepage

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

We’re deploying a new slate landing page on our stack. There’s an action button that seems to be showing up for everyone in the top right of the page. Any way to either get rid of it or only show it for users of a particular given group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the action button with a snippet of document CSS.

The easiest way to figure this out is to right-click -> inspect on the element and find the top-level HTML element for the button - in this case it's the `sl-app-view-actions` element.

In the `Styles` tab in your Slate document, simply add:
`sl-app-view-actions { display: none }`

Note that with the 'Actions' dropdown hidden, you'll need to manually navigate to the `/edit` URL to access edit mode or access edit mode through the actions on the Compass resource.

Your users will also no longer have access to the "Get Shareable View" or "View Source Datasets" actions.